# Extract details from bibliometrics data

Tags: data-mining, nlp, text-mining, social-network-analysis

I have set of bibliometrics data (references). I want to extract the author names, title and the name of the conference/journal from it. Since the referencing style used by different papers vary, I am interested in knowing if there are any per-existing tools to do it?

I am happy to provide examples if needed :)

Comment: Question is an year old as of today so I'm sure you might've found an answer. If not, my first question would be if you've tried Scopus?

Answer (score 0):

To learn from traditional software in that domain you could start at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software

Comment: Hmmm, I think what I am expecting is different. I want to know an API/tool that extracts information from the citation.

Comment: well, the above reference gives you a broad overview of the existing standards that these citations could follow.